# PHP json_encode - create JSON array

Tags: php, json

I've used the json_encode function in the past to create simply JSON objects like this:

```
$payload =  array ("user" => $username, "password" => $password, "group" => $group);
$payload = json_encode ($payload);
```

which creates this:

```
{"user":"john smith","password":"abc12345","group":"sales"}
```

I now need to generate a JSON array like this:

```
{
  "query": [
    {
      "Date": "11/01/2017...12/31/2017"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I can't find the correct syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multidimensional array PHP-JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454208/multidimensional-array-php-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a 2d array in php.

```
$payload =  array (
    "query" => array(
         array(
             "date" => "11/01/2017...12/31/2017",
             "other sub key" => "other sub value"
         )
    ),
    "other main key" => array(
         array(
             "other sub key" => "other sub value",
             etc...
         )
    )
);
```

Comment: This will make `query` an object but OP wants an array

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, in my code "query" is a key, not an array...

Comment: I mean the value of the `query` property in the resulting JSON. Your code will produce `"query":{"date":"11/01/2017...12/31/2017"}` (an object value) whereas OP wants `"query":[{"Date":"11/01/2017...12/31/2017"}]` (an array value)

Comment: Ah, I see, I missed and array. I edited my answer so that it fits now.

Answer (score 2):

That would be something like this

```
$array = array(
    'query' => array(
        array('Date' => '11-01-2017')
        )
    );


echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Result

```
{
    "query": [
        {
            "Date": "11-01-2017"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$payload = json_encode($payload, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php